# What is the proper way to send data from one fragment to another?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments

I have a `Fragment` with a "pick a year" button. This button adds a `ListFragment` to the backstack, where the user can pick a year. Once a year is chosen, I want to dispose of the `ListFragment` and return to the first fragment. What is the best way to update the first fragment, with the data that was selected in the `ListFragment`?

TL;DR: Fragment1 opens Fragment2, user chooses option in Fragment2. How do I update Fragment1 with this data?

My current solution is a public class with static members, but I'm wondering if `Android` has a better way.

Comment: Actually a bundle wouldnt work because the onCreateView of the first fragment wont be called, as the view is already created. I think his best bet is  an interface.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> All Fragment-to-Fragment communication is done through the associated
>   Activity. Two Fragments should never communicate directly. [[Source](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)]

Define an interface in Fragment2, and implement this interface in the host Activity. When you call the interface method from Fragment2, you can then access Fragment1 from inside the interface method on the Activity and pass the appropriate data to Fragment1 via its public methods.

**Create an interface:**

```
public class Fragment2 extends ListFragment {
    OnItemSelectedListener mCallback;

    public interface OnItemSelectedListener {
        public void onItemSelected(int position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mCallback = (OnItemSelectedListener ) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnItemSelectedListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        mCallback.onItemSelected(position);
    }
}
```

**Add `implements Fragment2.OnItemSelectedListener` to your activity definition, and define the onItemSelected method:**

```
public void onItemSelected(int position) {
    Fragment1 fragment = (Fragment1)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment1);

    if (fragment != null) {
        fragment.updateValue(position);
    }
}
```